# plot acf of several timeseries in one plot

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I am trying to alter the acf plot produced in R and am having no luck. My goal is to plot several autocorrelations in one plot and, instead of using the standard histogram, I would like to plot the autocorrelations as lines using different colors, so it is easy to distinguish between the different autocorrelations. The plot should also include the 95% confidence interval (similar as in the picture).

My goal would look something like this:

[image: Example picture]

Edit: As you can see, the acf result for the 0 day are also excluded.

So far my code looks like the following:

```
ACFdata <- merge(returns$companyA, returns$companyB)
ACF <- acf(ACFdata, na.action=na.pass, plot=FALSE)
```

So basically I only have the acf results and no clear idea of how to plot the acf results in a combined plot with colored lines.

Edit:

```
dput(ACF)
structure(list(acf = structure(c(1, 0.145125809377954, 0.142861039994255, 
0.0290589250361852, 0.124017821439246, 0.143011895498405, 0.105734336151885, 
0.0788661257638103, 0.0273805239429181, -0.118479508798021, 0.101475240804517, 
0.107529091607734, 0.0325071547524698, 0.15248825917752, 0.0345632600693495, 
0.105214927797195, 0.121820119834598, 0.106869630726315, 0.0957839598194307, 
-0.0908719122532893, -0.00734593289915199, 0.0178894474261508, 
0.0499571905134495, 0.0780855846282789, 0.0493591013094398, -0.0749535131984232, 
0.357086608389703, 0.246585751931129, -0.0629762920537067, 0.0395286467626801, 
0.0419665673763051, 0.00328571836147342, -0.00519232466623128, 
0.00483533922926756, -0.0250664920310689, -0.0876036092345946, 
0.0627421774389966, 0.135479194083771, 0.0626078698366847, 0.101742576940549, 
0.168581486338436, 0.0471250703324634, 0.0340518458280056, 0.0758087712436733, 
0.0124645208996951, -0.0277606211509939, -0.0341158520505214, 
-0.0644578776612549, -0.045110487814526, -0.0623504592674428, 
-0.0351696262152127, 0.058995956134521, 0.357086608389703, 0.0252501548107572, 
0.0611739122500323, 0.215137916544862, 0.183625254355587, 0.124460309708319, 
0.138507997600327, 0.040228791497421, 0.0140766070862445, -0.0799271843641712, 
0.017348973311441, 0.0952746355608701, 0.0404310918206657, 0.0632714503581609, 
-0.0257358208892062, 0.0599565925085307, 0.0384859490239319, 
0.0886012309614729, 0.0596889523276417, 0.0533055470088723, 0.0770419303845914, 
0.0840758532202191, 0.0518662906637178, 0.0399131621778747, 0.0202505502465014, 
-0.0105112241804381, 1, 0.12202126664333, -0.0380896874570601, 
0.171699455089945, 0.0921701048038319, -0.107621049165039, 0.0206611931650316, 
-0.00519190992729939, -0.0631090559052638, -0.0978803261385059, 
-0.0277111483321292, 0.064129198291785, -0.0932937679361303, 
0.0798459519613646, 0.0889483107174154, -0.0116665547060194, 
0.00663627461258374, 0.135982611207688, -0.0258901243417071, 
0.11835604048827, 0.100938356006999, 0.0132499377804722, 0.0534896127278462, 
0.00128064337860851, -0.0690617100695171, 0.0814839944828229), .Dim = c(26L, 
2L, 2L)), type = "correlation", n.used = 778L, lag = structure(c(0, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 
19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, 
-9, -10, -11, -12, -13, -14, -15, -16, -17, -18, -19, -20, -21, 
-22, -23, -24, -25, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 0, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25), .Dim = c(26L, 2L, 2L)), series = "test", 
    snames = c("returns$companyA", "returns$companyB"
    )), .Names = c("acf", "type", "n.used", "lag", "series", 
"snames"), class = "acf")
```

Comment: No example visible. Need you to post output from `dput(returns)`

Comment: Yeah that's way too much data to be able to paste it into here.
My returns are time series of several hundred companies, i.e. a time-indexed data frame which contains (log)returns.

I'll post the output of dput(ACF) instead, since it's considerable less data.

Comment: So how did you make the plot above? What code did you run? Is all the data needed to plot included in the posted data?

Comment: I didn't make the plot - that plot is used in a paper and I would like  to create a similar plot with my data.

The code I run (see my code excerpt above) results in the data which I've also listed above (the dput part).

What I would like to do now is transform my data into that plot.

Comment: So you want a plot with lag on the x-axis, acf on the y-axis, and one line for companyA and a different color for companyB with 95% confidence intervals for both. A horizontal line at y=0. (Not sure what those other red lines are.)

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I want - however manually the plot is not what I had in mind.

The function acf automatically generates a histogram of the acf data output - what I would like to do instead is creating the above chart automatically from the acf data (if that is possible).

Comment: `?plot.acf` indicates that you can request lines rather than a hist, with `type='l'`. To overlay lines onto a single plot, though, you probably need to access the data in the `acf` and `lag` elements of your `ACF` object.

Comment: Too bad, that's what I feared. When I run the acf function on my multivariate time-series, it only calculates values for 5-6 lags..seems like there is some issue with using too many time series at once. When I run acf on a subset of ~5 time series, I can still access >20 lags.

Seems like there is no fast/easy way..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you look at `str(ACF)`:

```
> str(ACF)
List of 6
 $ acf   : num [1:26, 1:2, 1:2] 1 0.1451 0.1429 0.0291 0.124 ...
 $ type  : chr "correlation"
 $ n.used: int 778
 $ lag   : num [1:26, 1:2, 1:2] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
 $ series: chr "test"
 $ snames: chr [1:2] "returns$companyA" "returns$companyB"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "acf"
```

You see that the `$acf` element is an array with the last two dimensions controlling which series acf or ccf result is being referenced. Then `plot(ACF)` which shows you that the default plotting mechanism puts multiple plots on the same page (which you are trying to avoid.) So run:

```
> plot(ACF, type="l", max.mfrow=1, ylim=c(-.2,.4))
Hit <Return> to see next plot: 
Hit <Return> to see next plot: 
Hit <Return> to see next plot: 
Hit <Return> to see next plot:
```

So "back up" to the first plot using your user interface for the interactive plot device, and then add the data from the otehr series using whatever colors and line widths you choose:

```
> lines(ACF$acf[-1, 2,1], lty=3, col="red", lwd=3)
> lines(ACF$acf[-1, 2,2], lty=2, col="orange", lwd=3)
> lines(ACF$acf[-1, 1,2], lty=2, col="blue", lwd=2)
```

I did not omit the first period but rather limited the y-range for plotting. That was simpler and allowed me to accept the default `plot.acf` function's choice of confidence bands rather than trying to construct them myself. You will need to change the title and probably put in a legend, but that should be trivial if you understand the base-graphic commands.

[image]