# ACF plot with multiple time-series in R

Tags: r, time-series, cross-correlation

I want to follow up on this thread, as it's over 2 years old and I also can't comment because I do not have enough posts, yet.

[plot acf of several timeseries in one plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23965892/plot-acf-of-several-timeseries-in-one-plot/23971755#23971755)

I would like to understand why all additional lines start at lag=1 and not 0. How can I have them start at lag=0 like the first one?

Also, is there a way to extend the x-axis to negative values? When I do pairwise ccf, I get values from -10 to +10, which nicely shows the pattern I'm looking for, but with acf I only get lags of either -6 or +6.

[image: ACF matrix]

[image: CCF plot]

[image: Multiple lines]

Also, please apologize my ignorance, but what does the dashed blue line at 0.4 represent? Significance? I've seen the line at various values in different examples. 
Thank you in advance.

Here the code, I basically used the same as in the link above.

```
> data3     
         Maui8      Maui7       Maui6     Olowalu      Maalaea
1   1.01532397  0.7583463 -1.45102480  0.37355214  0.093384619
2   0.84997103  0.7802248 -1.47906584  0.57370139  0.000741584
3   0.65297103  0.9325412 -1.31256709  0.29211557  0.077706758
4   0.42029456  0.8041302 -1.36599992  0.15763796  0.018583624
5   0.15063769  0.5932333 -1.00933326 -0.03478742  0.073490340
6   0.14522593  0.4739607 -0.82896012  0.22469641  0.226357256
7   0.03779456  0.4774847 -0.09524122  0.42900612  0.194261484
8  -0.39651917 -0.2433839  0.07535580 -0.03204488  0.384578649
9  -0.99220544 -1.3080379  0.07143167 -0.57821403  0.012594818
10 -1.58116623 -1.3739277 -0.28876112 -1.34129239 -0.543698715
11 -1.68365642 -1.5527201  0.35511326 -0.99125508 -0.574656426
12 -1.67555838 -1.6044574  0.21679237 -1.05519787 -0.731770854
13 -1.64012701 -1.6975577  0.68442918 -1.20809587 -0.888636526
14 -1.22618583 -1.3975012  0.94365182 -0.84284090 -0.611341749
15 -1.12916623 -0.8248387  1.05953344 -0.86989314 -0.242448715
16 -1.11394684 -0.3294150  1.41744881 -0.45954904 -0.331766245
17 -0.41821140 -0.4312582  1.19811924 -0.45322699 -0.384893352
18  0.22428860 -0.2696410  1.14340119 -0.28008162 -0.323007387
19  0.69397114 -0.1249800  1.12954154  0.48571412  0.074298377
20  1.55118345  1.1953590  0.91711047  1.47251236  0.802606648
21  1.76527075  1.6837135  0.50540620  1.30325798  0.951992613
22  1.34356440  1.6247940 -0.09836573  1.21764394  0.794730708
23  1.59601480  0.9492149 -0.69564643  0.87988078  0.490006397
24  1.41023107  0.8847163 -1.09236948  0.73676048  0.436886096

> ACF<-acf(data3)
> plot(ACF, type="l", max.mfrow=1)
> lines(ACF$acf[-1, 2,3], lty=1, col="red", lwd=1)
> lines(ACF$acf[-1, 2,4], lty=1, col="green", lwd=1)
```

Comment: From `acf` and `plot.acf`: Blue lines represent the confidence interval of an uncorrelated series. Additional lines most likely start at 1 because lag 0 is fixed to 1 by default. However, this is just a guess, without any code as to how to plot was produced I'm can't tell.

Comment: I added the code above.